# cordova project generates apk in wrong path

Tags: android, cordova

I have switched to a mac from a windows. Now when I run 'cordova build android' it is building successfully and generating an apk in `/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk` but this apk isnt working properly.

On my windows machine I go through the exact same steps and it builds a working apk in a different directory - `/platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-debug.apk`.

You can see the the apks are named differently - the one generated from windows machine is right.

I thought it may have something to do with ant but I have the exact same version and it is running on the machine fine. I thought it could have something to do with the ant environment variable as well but I don't think thats it either. This is what I have

```
/Users/myMachine/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the Mac-built APK?

Comment: It doesn't get passed the second screen of my app - when it tries to contact to the server I believe. I find it weird that it generates the apk in two completely seperate places. there must be some differenct when its an ant build

Comment: Could it be my environment variables? in my bash.profile i have... export PATH={$PATH}:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/lk/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/lk/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/lk/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin

Comment: When the build runs on windows it executes... Running command: C:\Users\App\Desktop\MyApp\platforms\android\cordova\build
.bat
Buildfile: C:\Users\App\Desktop\MyApp\platforms\android\build.xml

Comment: On mac it is executing Running command: /Users/lk/Desktop/MyApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/lk/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/lk/Desktop/MyApp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/lk/Desktop/FrontEnd/platforms/android/build.gradle